# Is there a better way I can set up this sequence to improve performance?

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

So I managed to get a esb prototype working. Basically we use two proxies/sequences to pull in two XML files via VFS that we need to parse through and send the data to a DSS service so the data is inserted into a table. When we use a small file (around 500 kb - 2200 rows of data or so) the flow works fine and the table will update after a few minutes. I believe this is because I am iterating through all the rows and sending that data one at a time to the DSS for insertion.

When I use a larger file (about 50MB - about 217440 rows of data), the proxy will lock the file and take about 15 to 30 seconds to consume the data but I never see the data get to the DSS.

I have allocated 3GB of memory for the ESB and after I post the file to the 'in' directory, I see it rise and hover around 2.0 - 2.5 GB and never lower. So I assume it is still processing the data.

One thing I just noticed as I was typing this, in the mediation tracer I noticed the last entry was at the Iterator. So maybe it's getting hung up there with the filter? Do I need to use something different than the iterator?

Is wso2esb designed to handle files this large in size? I'm anticipating files sizes up to 250MB (or 1329313 rows of data in the XML). I've seen references to using Smooks and JMS but i'm not sure if that fits in this case since for very large files the ESB can't even pull it in from the proxy.

Thank you.

here is a copy of my sequence/proxy I'm using in the ESB.

Proxy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MyProxy"
       transports="https,http,local,vfs"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="targetfilename" value="TITLES"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <clone>
            <target sequence="MySequence"/>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///var/process/rroriginal</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///var/process/rrin</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///var/process/rrfault</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">TITLES.xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Sequence

```
    <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MySequence">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="sequence" value="MySequence"></property>
   </log>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="filename" expression="get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')"></property>
   <log level="custom">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="show-name" expression="get-property('filename')"></property>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="file-name" expression="get-property('targetfilename')"></property>
   </log>
   <iterate xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:z="RowsetSchema" expression="//z:row" id="It1">
      <target>
         <sequence>
            <property name="Id" expression="//z:row/@ID"></property>
            <property name="vch" expression="//z:row/@vch"></property>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="showids" expression="get-property('Id')"></property>
               <property name="showvch" expression="get-property('vch')"></property>
            </log>
            <filter xpath="//z:row[starts-with(@vch, '978')]">
               <then>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                           <soapenv:Body>
                              <p:insert_AR_operation>
                                 <p:ID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</p:ID>
                                 <p:vch xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</p:vch>
                              </p:insert_AR_operation>
                           </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg expression="get-property('Id')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
                        <arg expression="get-property('vch')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <log level="custom">
                     <property name="sequence" value="Calling LevelsAR_ISBNService"></property>
                  </log>
                  <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2"></property>
                  <property name="SOAPAction" value="insert_AR_operation" scope="transport"></property>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://*.*.*.*:****/services/AR_Service.HTTPEndpoint/"></address>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </then>
               <else>
                  <log level="custom">
                     <property name="sequence" value="Condition Drop"></property>
                  </log>
                  <drop></drop>
               </else>
            </filter>
         </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>
   <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="fn:concat(get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss'), '-', get-property('filename'))" scope="transport"></property>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"></property>
</sequence>
```

Comment: I'm new to wso2 esb, i have a doubt, why you have used clone mediator? as you are calling only one sequence.. Why can't you use send or call mediator as per your requirement.

Comment: It's probably a copy paste error. We were experimenting with a lot at that time. Regarding performance smooks is the way to go with large files. We made the switch a while ago andthere was a huge jump in performance; but hit a bump with the jms call. Stepped away from wso2 for now but will mess with it some more in the future.